# sqlite y bases de datos

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, jupyter

Estoy iniciándome en el uso de bases de datos con jupyter notebook, he escrito un código en el que se introduce una serie de elementos, en este caso coches, en una base de datos creada previamente por mí en el prompt de Anaconda. El código es el siguiente

```
 import sqlite3 as lite
 import sys
 con=lite.connect('test.db')
 with con:
     cur=con.cursor()
     cur.execute("CREATE TABLE if not exists Cars(Id INT, Name TEXT, 
                  Price INT)")
     cur.execute("INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(1,'Audi',52642)")
     cur.execute("INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(2,'Mercedes',57127)")
     cur.execute("INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(3,'Skoda',9000)")
     cur.execute("INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(4,'Volvo',29000)")
     cur.execute("INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(5,'Bentley',350000)")
     cur.execute("INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(6,'Citroen',21000)")
     cur.execute("INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(7,'Hummer',41400)")
     cur.execute("INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(8,'Volkswagen',21600)")
```

Y después cuando voy a comprobar en el prompt de Anaconda si funciona el código, me sale esto

```
 (base) C:\Users\jonas>sqlite3 test.db
 SQLite version 3.35.4 2021-04-02 15:20:15
 Enter ".help" for usage hints.
 sqlite> .mode column
 sqlite> .headers on
 sqlite> SELECT * FROM Cars;
 Error: no such table: Cars
 sqlite>
```

Si alguien me puede ayudar se lo agradecería, saludos

Answer (score 2):

Este error es debido a que se olvido realizar el respectivo commit a la base de datos, recuerda siempre hacer los commits a la base de datos (Son commits del propio sqlite)
Para eso simplemente tienes que agregar la siguiente linea al final de tu codigo:

```
# guardar (commit) los cambios
con.commit()
```

Una vez realizado esto ya estarian los cambios en la base de datos,recuerdaque si no vas volver a utilizar la conexion es recomendable cerrarla de la siguiente manera:

```
con.close()
```

Espero haberte ayudado, saludos :)

Comment: Ademas, recuerda que si quieres hacer un salto de linea correctamente, tienes que colocar las triple comillas simples, esto debido a que si no se hace de esta manera el sqlite no reconocera la sentecia, ejemplo:

cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE cars
                   (date text, trans text, symbol text, qty real, price real)'''

Comment: Hola buenas tardes, disculpa que te moleste, pero hice los cambios y me sigue dando el mismo error. Gracias de antemano y un saludo